# How to set routes for a controller in MVC. Always returns "HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, .net-4.0, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am trying to set the route in Global.asax for the following controller, but I always get **HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found**

**AssetsController.cs**

```
public class AssetsController : Controller
{
  public ActionResult Index(string aDesc, string fDate)
  {
    ViewBag.DateFrom = fDate.ToString();
    ViewBag.AssetDescription = aDesc.ToString();
    return View();
  }
 }
```

**Global.asax.cs**

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{

    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.MapRoute("Assets", "Assets/{action}/{aDesc}/{fDate}",
            new { controller = "Assets", action = "Index", aDesc = "", fDate = "" }
        );

        // Show a 404 error page for anything else.
        routes.MapRoute("Error", "{*url}",
            new { controller = "Error", action = "404" }
        );
    }

    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        AuthConfig.RegisterAuth();

    }
}
```

When I access the view using the following URL, everything works fine and as expected:

```
http://localhost/Assets/Index/?aDesc=090&fDate=20130701000000
```

But when I access the view using following URL, I get 404.0 error message (error shown below)

```
http://localhost/Assets/Index/090/20130701000000
```

**Error: HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found The resource you are looking for has been
removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.**

AppPool is set to .NET 4.0 Integrated Mode

HTTP Redirection and Static Content is checked under Common HTTP Features (Windows Features On/Off)

Comment: I wonder if this problem has something to do with the WebAPI setup and the fact that the WebAPI's routes are being set first?

Comment: JayC I had to register the route in RouteConfig.cs to fix it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure your route is working beyond the default, as you're explicitly providing the parameters. Try registering your route in RouteConfig.cs

http://www.jondavis.net/techblog/post/2012/06/23/ASPNET-MVC-4-Where-Have-All-The-Globalasax-Routes-Gone.aspx

Comment: Thanks B Cotter. I fixed this issue last night. It was exactly what you have specified above. I fixed it by registering the route in App_Start > RouteConfig.cs. Will mark your answer as correct instead of answering my own question and accepting it. Thanks.